# Python instance counter in ProcessPool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having trouble finding the correct way to implement the following: I have a class in Python3 for which I keep an instance counter. Using a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, I submit several tasks that make use of this class. I assumed that since the tasks ran in separate processes there would be no shared state between them, but it would seem I was wrong as this instance counter is shared among them. The following code exemplifies what I mean:

```py
import concurrent.futures

class A:
     counter = 0
     def __init__(self):
         A.counter += 1
         self.id = A.counter
     def hello(self):
         return f'Hello from node{self.id}'

def start():
     instance = A()
     return instance.hello()

results = []
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
     for i in range(4):
         f = executor.submit(start)
         results.append(f)

for r in results:
     print(r.result())
```

The output from the above is:

```
Hello from node1
Hello from node2
Hello from node1
Hello from node1
```

The issue is not the race condition when accessing the counter, my issue is that the variable is even shared at all when I was expecting it to be private per process (e.g. start at 0 for each worker). What would be a pythonic way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NameError: name 'start' is not defined` - please fix your [mre].

Comment: Whoops, my bad, thanks for pointing this out @wwii. I have updated my code and checked that it runs.

Comment: Why did you close it? I can fully answer the question, it's pretty simple... @wwii

Comment: I didn't close it! :( Not sure who did. I just voted to re-open it. I could really use the help.

Comment: @Dash83 well I'll just answer here until we get another reopen vote.

Comment: The memory for each process is private as you assumed, but you make a different assumption that is incorrect - who says these are different processes?

Comment: Remember it's a queue of tasks. When a worker finishes it takes the next task, but the workers are the same workers. The processes do not restart between tasks

Comment: @Bharel ha! Yes! I just ran into that myself by adding `os.getpid()` to the string returned by `hello()`. It seems I can fix this by adding `maxtasksperchild=1` to the Pool constructor. Any other insight you can offer into how to approach this task? I'll be glad to accept your answer once they reopen this question.

Comment: @Dash83 well it highly depends on what you're trying to achieve. In most cases I'd not recommend your solution. It creates an enormous overhead. Tasks are usually small things. Starting a new process for every one is exactly what process pool is trying to prevent.

Comment: @Bharel in my case, these tasks are longish computations (seconds to minutes), so the overhead (in time) of starting a new process shouldn't be too much of an impact. I'd more concerned if I need to be wary about other limits, like how many processes can the pool start, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it would seem you found that tasks are not always evenly distributed between workers within a processing pool, and one of the workers managed to complete 2 "tasks" while one (of the 4) got none. In each worker the `A` class is defined either by copying the memory space from the time at which `fork` is called (*nix) or from `import`ing the main file (Windows and MacOS). The class attribute `counter` behaves like a global variable, because it was not defined as an instance attribute, so any worker getting multiple tasks will see that value incremented each time. While it is possible to avoid this by limiting workers to only completing one task each before they're terminated and re-started, it's generally good practice to avoid global state in general. `maxtasksperchild` is much more frequently used to clean up instances where child processes may for various reasons not release memory or file handles over time to prevent leaks.

As you have stated in the comments, a long running task reduces the relative impact of the overhead of re-starting the process each task, however if you are using any of the functions that map a function over an iterable, and accept a `chunksize` argument, this approach may break. A "task" isn't specifically one iteration of the map, but may be several at once (to reduce overhead of transferring the arguments and results). This example should demonstrate a pool with `maxtasksperchild=1`, where each child ends up calling `start()` 4 times:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
class A:
     counter = 0
     def __init__(self):
         A.counter += 1
         self.id = A.counter
     def hello(self):
         return f'Hello from node{self.id}'

def start(_):
     instance = A()
     print( instance.hello())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1) as p:
        p.map(start, range(16), chunksize=4)
```